# how to echo fixer.io json php

Tags: php, fixer.io

Hi I'm trying get a json from fixer.io and then for each rates echo it but cant get it to work. 
 the code are

```
<?php

    function usd(){
      echo 'HEJ test';
      $fixer_access_key = my_access_key;
      $url= 'https://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=' . $fixer_access_key;
      echo $url;  
      $json = file_get_contents($url);
      $data = json_decode($json);
        echo $url . "<br>";
                echo 'printing json foreach <br>';
        foreach($data as $obj){
            echo '...';
            $prefix = $obj;
            echo $prefix;
            echo '<br>';}
echo 'done printing json foreach';
}
usd();  ?>
```

and the result are:

https://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=my_fixer_key

printing json foreach

done printing json foreach

Comment: I'd start with `var_dump($data)`. Is the response valid JSON, what is actually returned from `json_decode`?

Comment: Please copy/paste all the info into the question itself. Add an example json, the result you're currently getting and how the expected result should be. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And maybe check your error reporting / logs. Assuming answer so far provided you would be getting error `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

use

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

This should allow foreacha to works - however you will only see first level of json object keys (not nested ones). The second parameter of  `json_decode` change result from object to array.

You will also need to change foreach - to following: `foreach($data as $key => $obj)` and inside it `echo $obj` to `echo $key;`.

Here is simplified working [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc1ac76090a188c4418361ed109e9f1ec41f7eac).

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

If working `foreach` is not your goal but rather pretty printed json, then instead use following code:

```
  $json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  echo $json_string;
```